# why does dim(df[,1]) of a dataframe with two columns and three rows have size 0

Tags: r

I'm trying this in R

```
> df <- data.frame(x=c("spam", "spam", "ham"), y=c("some mail", "some other mail", "some third mail"))
> add.string.func <- function(somestr) { paste("prefix-", somestr, "-postfix", sep = "") }
> df[1,]
     x         y
1 spam some mail
> df[,1]
[1] spam spam ham 
Levels: ham spam
> apply(X = df[1,], add.string.func, MARGIN = 1)
     1                         
[1,] "prefix-spam-postfix"     
[2,] "prefix-some mail-postfix"
> apply(X = as.matrix(df[,1]), add.string.func, MARGIN = 1)
[1] "prefix-spam-postfix" "prefix-spam-postfix" "prefix-ham-postfix" 
> apply(X = df[,1], add.string.func, MARGIN = 1)
Error in apply(X = df[, 1], add.string.func, MARGIN = 1) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length ### Why is the dim 0?
> dim(df)
[1] 3 2  # doesn't this means it's 3 rows and 2 columns??
> dim(df)
[1] 3 2
```

if `dim(df)` is `3 2` how come `dim[,1]` is NULL?

Comment: Indeed, it is a duplicate

Comment: Because when selecting only 1 column we are losing the dimension as it becomes a vector, it has a length. Compare `dim(mtcars[, 1])` vs `dim(mtcars[, 1, drop = FALSE])`.